# Can't find mysqld.sock

Tags: server, lamp

I am kinda new to this

So I use this to turn off mysql in linus ubuntu server

```
#uname -r
4.4.0-87-generic
```

ok so when I try to run a database_instaler.sh y check the log and I see

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

But I am using Lampp and I cant find the mysqld.sock file inside the mysql directory.

Can someone please give me a hand? where can I find .sock?

Comment: The mysql server looks for /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock but the mysql.sock file was in xampp folder so i used

 find / -name '*.sock'
to find the mysql.sock file and then used

ln -s <the file location> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
to get a link for the *.sock file then tried mysql and it ran without error. Hope this could solve yours.

Remember to create the directory if it does not exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicates that MySQL is not running or it has not been installed correctly.  You access MySQL with a MySQL client, such as the `mysql` command.  The MySQL client communicates with the MySQL server over a TCP/IP port, or a Unix socket.

In your case the MySQL client is configured to communicate with the server over a Unix socket located at `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` but there is no server listening there.

This could indicate

- No MySQL server is installed
- Your MySQL server is stopped
- Your MySQL server is configured to listen to a socket at a different location, or to a TCP/IP port, but your MySQL client thinks it is listening to a socket at that location.

Comment: The mysql server looks for /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock but the mysql.sock file was in xampp folder so i used

 find / -name '*.sock'
to find the mysql.sock file and then used

ln -s <the file location> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
to get a link for the *.sock file then tried mysql and it ran without error. Hope this could solve yours.

Remember to create the directory if it does not exists.